# What is the amount airflow needed from Aquarium Air pump per minute to make a DIY CPAP?

Tags: pumps, airflow, biomedical-engineering, medical-devices

I am trying to make DIY Bubble CPAP that can put a constant pressure on patient.
I am using an Aquarium Oxygen pump as air source. 
The motor says 38L/Min in the spec. And by googling I found that an average adult can takes up to 7L/min air while resting.
But when I used it, I felt like I am getting very low air flow.

Can anyone help, what am I missing?

Incase you there is any suggestion please drop it too. 
Thank you.

Comment: 7l/min? That seems low, perhaps 4 to 7 litres per breath and then how many breaths per minute?

Comment: Yeah, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lung_volumes) has average adult lung capacity at around 6 liters, so Solar Mike's comment is probably correct.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. 
The link below says 7-8 Litres of Oxygen
But it's not just pure Oxygen. There are other airs too.

https://www.sharecare.com/health/air-quality/oxygen-person-consume-a-day

Comment: It would be an idea to make sure you get this right **before** you kill yourself or someone else.

Comment: I held the mask with hand. So when the airflow was low, I could easily remove the mask and breathe.

Answer (score 1):

A medical device known as an [incentive inspirometer](https://www.drugs.com/cg/how-to-use-an-incentive-spirometer.html) measures volume of air inhaled. Twenty years ago, I could pull five liters (was serious cyclist) but now I'm down to four liters per breath. Sixteen breaths per minute means sixty-four liters per minute.

At the five liter value, that's eighty liters per minute, in resting state.

[image: incentive inspirometer image]

Comment: I did an exercise with students to show how much air they used per minute and compared the total to the volume of air in the room - explaining the reasons for ventilation in rooms & buildings. Used party balloons - they had to blow them up with 4 breaths, then we approximated the volume from the diameter and divided by four... A fun exercise.

Comment: Thank you, 
I think I am heading in the right direction. 
The source where I found 7L/min was actually total Oxygen per minute. 
So the total air in litre will be much more. 
Which is around 80L/Min the amount you mentioned. 

Thank you